# Seam 3 - retrieve all seam components in application context

Tags: seam, seam3

is there a way to get all the Seam 3 component classes which are @ApplicationScoped?

Answer (score 2):

Didn't try myself, just a guess after reading `16.5. The Bean interface` chapter of Weld [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e4994)

```
class ApplicationScopedBeans {
    @Inject BeanManager beanManager;

    public Set<Bean<?>> getApplicationScopedBeans() {
        Set<Bean<?>> allBeans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});
        Set<Bean<?>> result = new HashSet<Bean<?>>();
        for(Bean<?> bean : allBeans) {
            if(bean.getScope().equals(ApplicationScoped.class)) {
                result.add(bean);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

To obtain an `instance` of a `Bean`:

```
public Object getApplicationScopedInstance(Bean<?> bean) {
    CreationalContext ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
    Context appCtx = beanManager.getContext(ApplicationScoped.class);
    return appCtx.get(bean, ctx);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Looks like all above misses the whole point of CDI :)

```
class ApplicationScopedBeans {
    @Inject @ApplicationScoped Instance<Object> appScopedBeans;

}
```

Comment: hi , can you tell me how to achieve Contexts.getEventContext() in  seam 3

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call a method from a component in applicationContext or use a field in this, it's better that u define it as producer method or field and inject it where u want.

Answer (score 0):

You would use  `getApplicationContext()` to get the context, and then the `getNames()` to get all names of things that are application scope, and then you would use `get()`to retrieve them by name.

What are you trying to do?  From there you would have to use reflection to get them to the right type..

```
Context appContext = Contexts.getApplicationContext();
String [] names = appContext.getNames();
//Do whatever with them..
for(String s : names){
   Object x = appContext.get(name);
   // do something.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not for Seam2? OP wants for Seam3

Comment: Yup, that's exactly how I did it before, in SEAM 2... I'll remove the donwvote if you give me an answer for seam 3 :-p